# How do I get full power supply voltage across load?

Tags: voltage, h-bridge

Why doesen't load have full voltage of power supply? I even tried with BJTs (both PNP&NPN) and even pmos yet none yielded full power supply voltage across load. Raising gate voltages does not help. Voltage source to thyristor gate has series resistance to limit gate current. Can a full bridge even provide full voltage?

**nmos**
[image]

**thyristor**
[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. We need details please. Source voltage and maximum current into a load. The details of your load and the ON resistance of your switchs.

Comment: What are you talking about, the load is in the full bridge with specified resistance.

Answer (score 1):

A full bridge can provide more or less full voltage if biassed correctly.

Use NMOS at the bottom, bias the gate positive with respect to the ground (the easy bit). Use PMOS at the top, and bias the gate negative with respect to the top rail (the hard bit, as it involves level shifting). That way, both top and bottom drivers will have minimal voltage drop.

Comment: Did as you suggested (thank you) replaced top fets with pmos. But huge currents are flowing thru the bridge.

Comment: Huge currents can flow through the bridge if you turn on top and bottom devices at the same time. This is called 'shoot-through', and is to be avoided. Check the drive phasing of your top and bottom devices, it's easy to make a mistake. The correct way is to turn top-left, bottom-right, and then switch to the other diagonal pair. In a practical bridge, the drive timing of top and bottom devices will be deliberately skewed slightly, so the on devices start to get turned off earlier, a few 10s of nS, before the off devices get turned on, to avoid shoot through.

Comment: Shoot thru is exactly whats happening, are all of ltspice's pmos models depletion? Because all pmos models I tried  are normally closed.

Comment: This is 'the dog ate my homework' stuff. Find out how to drive the devices, individually, so that you know how to drive them, and which way is on, and which off, then put them together into an H bridge. You can also use nmos devices at the top, though of course, like all FETs, their gates have to be driven with respect to their sources, which move, so that's more difficult yet again. Drive ICs are sold for the purpose.